# java drawing rectangle with nested loop

Tags: java

I have a homework for college. I have to draw a rectangle with nested for loop that looks like this:

```
    1
   234
  34567
 4567890
567890123
```

for now I managed to do this:

```
public class DN2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        trikotnik(8);  

    }
    static void trikotnik(int n){
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = n; j > i; j--) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j > 1; j--) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your program currently print?

Comment: It prints this:

      1 
    2 1 2  
  3 2 1 2 3  etc...
  1

Comment: sorry I don' know how to make it go in new line here

Comment: isn't this a triangle? Also, if this is homework you should figure it out yourself.

Comment: @user3378249 just [edit] your original post if you have additional information you need to include.

Comment: Yes I agree it is a homework :D but I need just some advice.

Comment: I think there's a bug in `for (int j = 1; j > 1; j--)` - it seems to me that this loop would never be iterated, because if `j = 1`, it's not `> 1`.

Answer (score 0):

To draw a triangle, at most you need two nested loops, one to deal with rows and another to deal with columns.

```
 for (int y=0; y<5; y++)
 {
   for (int x=0; x<9; x++)
   {
      //write character that should be at (x,y), i.e. (column, row)
   }
 }
```

You haven't specified anything about which numbers to should be printed where so I'm not going to guess at an algorithm but

```
for (int j = 1; j > 1; j--)
```

is saying, set `j` to 1 and while it is greater than one, decrement it. As you've set it to one, it can never be greater than one so this loop is skipped completely

Comment: It seems that the number printed in position `i` in row `j` is `( i + j - 1 ) % 10`.  Also, your code draws a rectangle, not a triangle.

Comment: yeah, I thought about my downvote and retracted it.  It's a bit ambiguous whether the OP is after a rectangle or a triangle.  If I didn't happen to know that "trikotnik" means "triangle", I also wouldn't know what to answer.

Comment: I'll let you know how it goes.